# Accepting A IENUMERABLE model post in a controller in mvc 3 vb.net?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4

I have a view in my app that uses a @modeltype ienumerable of (xxxxxxx.abc), and uses a for each loop to populate the view. This view has select boxes that show up next to each item in the view. When I post the form to the controller accepting it as a formcollection does not work, and if I accept it like: `ByVal abc as abc` it says that its an invalid model.. The code is as follows:

```vb
<AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)>
Function ClassAttendance(ByVal Attendance As Attendance) As ActionResult
    If ModelState.IsValid Then
        UpdateModel(Attendance)
        db.SaveChanges()
         Return RedirectToAction("Index")
    End If
    Return View()
End Function
```

Any ideas?? Can I somehow use a for each loop in the view without making it ienumerable? If so when It posts to the controller my below code would just about work.. The only value that really matters is the selectlist choice and the id of the record that it was changed for...

The view is:

@ModelTYPE List(Of xxxxx.attendance)

```
@Code
ViewData("Title") = "Class Attendance Record"
End Code


@Using Html.BeginForm
@<fieldset>

<table>
<tr>
    <th>
        First Name
    </th>
    <th>
        Last Name
    </th>
    <th>
        Registrant ID
    </th>
    <th>
        Course Status
    </th>
    <th>
        Comments
    </th>

 </tr>

 @For r As Integer = 0 To ViewBag.count
    Dim i As Integer = r
    @Html.HiddenFor(Function(m) m(i).id)
 @<tr>

    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(Function(m) m(i).firstName)

    </td>

    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(Function(m) m(i).lastName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(Function(m) m(i).reg_id)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(Function(m) m(i).Completed_Class)
        </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DropDownList("Completed_Class", New SelectList(ViewBag.courseStatus, "Status", "Status"))

    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(m) m(i).Comments, New With {.class = "AttenComment"})
   </td>
 </tr>
 Next
 </table>
 <p>
     <input type="submit" name="submit" />
    </p>
 </fieldset>


 End Using
```

I have been over countless tut's and posts with no luck at all... I only want to update the model record for each record to the corresponding selected value from the selectlist... Thanks greatly for any and all help..

Comment: Check out this blog post http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

Comment: No dice.. This is not a sequential record model.. The view is only populated with items in the model that match criteria on the return view of the controller..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In brief, this can be done. There are many ways to accomplish this, the easiest by far I found was to have a custom view model which contains an array of the model you want to bulk insert.

```
public class MultipleAttendance
{
    public Attendance[] attendances {get;set;}
}
```

Then in your View you can loop as such:

```
@for(int i=0,i<10;i++)
{
    @Html.TextBox(attendances[i].firstName)
}
```

In the controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(MultipleAttendance model)
{
   // Get a value
   model.attendances[0].firstName;
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Please see my above code I have editted the view portion.. But now it is saying: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index             When it gets to the hiddenfor(function(m) m(i).id) line...

Comment: @Skindeep2366 Hey mate, is this still giving a problem?

Comment: Yeah I hacked a work around for it. But I have stepped off on another part of the project that is more important...